# Distance calculation bug android

Tags: android, android-location

Hi I have been doing the app for calculating the distance and speed of travelling. All the function of getting speed and distance working fine, however during the testing I saw the bug where the distance is getting started to be measured only if the speed is 19 Km/h +

Would anybody have any idea why this might be happening ?

Thanks

```
//initialize location listener
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            getSpeed(location);
            getDistance(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }

        //get the speed from the given location updates
        public void getSpeed(Location location) {
            currentSpeed = (location.getSpeed() * 3600 / 1000);
            String convertedSpeed = String.format("%.2f", currentSpeed);
            speedTxt.setText(convertedSpeed + "Km/h");
        }

        private void getDistance(Location location) {

            //to capture current location and keep as starting position of person
            if (pLat == 500.0 && pLng == 500.0 ){
                pLat = location.getLatitude();
                pLng = location.getLongitude();
            }

            if (cLat == 500.0 && cLng == 500.0){
                cLat = location.getLatitude();
                cLng=location.getLongitude();
            }

            //to check is the person has changed location
            if (pLat != cLat && pLng != cLng) {
                pLat = cLat;
                pLng = cLng;
            }

            //update the current location
            cLat = location.getLatitude();
            cLng = location.getLongitude();

            //call the calculation method
            distance += getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(cLat, cLng, pLat, pLng);
            String convertedDistance = String.format("%.2f", distance);
            distanceTxt.setText(" " + convertedDistance);
        }

        public double getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(Double cLat, Double cLng, Double pLat, Double pLng) {
            // CALCULATE DISTANCE BETWEEN TWO POINTS
            double earthRadius = 6367; //meters
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(cLat - pLat);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(cLng - pLng);
            double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(cLat)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pLat)) *
                            Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            double dist = (double) (earthRadius * c);
            dist = Math.round(dist * 100) / 100.0;

            return dist;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints function is going to return exactly 0 for small differences in location because of this line:

```
dist = Math.round(dist * 100) / 100.0;
```

Try rounding the total distance only for display purposes in GetDistance():

```
//call the calculation method
distance += getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(cLat, cLng, pLat, pLng);
String convertedDistance = String.format("%.2f", Math.round(dist * 100) / 100.0);
distanceTxt.setText(" " + convertedDistance);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getDistance(Location location) {

    //to capture current location and keep as starting position of person
    if (pLat == 500.0 && pLng == 500.0) {
        pLat = location.getLatitude();
        pLng = location.getLongitude();
    }

    if (cLat == 500.0 && cLng == 500.0) {
        cLat = location.getLatitude();
        cLng = location.getLongitude();
    }

    //to check is the person has changed location
    if (pLat != cLat && pLng != cLng) {
        pLat = cLat;
        pLng = cLng;
    }

    //update the current location
    cLat = location.getLatitude();
    cLng = location.getLongitude();

    //call the calculation method
    distance += getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(cLat, cLng, pLat, pLng);
    //String convertedDistance = String.format("%.2f", distance);
    String convertedDistance = String.format("%.2f", Math.round(distance * 100) / 100.0);
    distanceTxt.setText(" " + convertedDistance);
}

public double getDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(Double cLat, Double cLng, Double pLat, Double pLng) {
    // CALCULATE DISTANCE BETWEEN TWO POINTS
    double earthRadius = 6367; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(cLat - pLat);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(cLng - pLng);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(cLat)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pLat)) *
                    Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double dist = (double) (earthRadius * c);
    //dist = Math.round(dist * 100) / 100.0;

    return dist;
}
```